# Call instance method

Tags: php, class, oop

Is it possible static method to call instance method? 
Here is the code I have.

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    public static function mysqlToHuman($date)
    {
        return $this->format('d-m-Y');
    }

    public static function humanToMysql($date)
    {
        return $this->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}


echo MyDateTime::mysqlToHuman('2013-12-01');
```

and I get

```
Fatal error: Non-static method DateTime::format() cannot be called statically
```

If not how to achieve the desired effect as described above?

Comment: No. `$this` is not available in `static` methods, because there's no object.

Comment: See the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
class MyDateTime extends \DateTime
{
    private static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance;
        if (!$instance instanceof static) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public static function mysqlToHuman($date)
    {
        return static::getInstance()->format('d-m-Y');
    }

    public static function humanToMysql($date)
    {
        return static::getInstance()->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}

echo MyDateTime::mysqlToHuman('2013-12-01');
```

Comment: Yes but is this the best method to achieve that? I mean by calling $instance = new self() each time when I need an access to instance method

Comment: I updated the example with a more efficient instance generation. It will only happen the first time you access it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create the date object from the result:

```
$date = new \Datetime('2013-12-01');

echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // 01-12-2013
```

Or if you need a helper class with static methods:

```
$formatted = DateFormatter::mysqlToHuman($date);
echo $formatted; // 01-12-2013 - however you like.
```

There is no point in extending the class if you are only added static methods.